# android - Get the URI of a video using it's ID (Mediastore)

Tags: android, video, mediastore

I have the mediastore id for a video, found like so from a CursorAdapter:

```
Cursor cursor = mGalleryAdapter.getCursor();
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
Integer id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
```

How can I use the ID to get the URI of the video file (the URI being like the URI recieved  at *onActivityResult()* when you record a video)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just append the id to the provider URI. For example, for video file in external storage:

```
Uri vedioUri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
```